# Where like "* " in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a list of strings and some of them begin with "* " for example:
"* ThisIsAString", "* This is also a string".

I'd like to use a where clause to only select the strings that begin with "* " but, as * is the character used to specify continue to the end of string - I am having a hard time.

This is what I'm trying to do, sort of: `Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -like "* "}`

I'm sure this is possible but I've not found a way to do it after some digging online!

Comment: `$_.DisplayName -like '[*] *'` or `$_.DisplayName.StartsWith('* ')`.

Comment: @GertJanKraaijeveld: Yes, but note that it's not _escaping_ that is being used, it is a character _range_ / _set_; true escaping works too: `'* foo' -like '\`* *'`

Answer (score 2):

```
$_.DisplayName -like '[*] *'
```

or

```
$_.DisplayName.StartsWith('* ')
```

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Am I right that this does work, because inside a [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-5.1) wildcard characters are taken literal?

Comment: @LotPings: Yes, though note that - even though the docs call it that - `[...]` isn't just a _range_, without `-`, you can place characters next to each other to interpret them as a _set_ so that any individual character matches; e.g. `'whoa' -like 'wh[ao][oa]'`

Comment: @mklement0 Yes, **I**'m aware that the range/set is comparable to [RegEx Character Classes or Character Sets](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) just without negations and quantifiers. I wanted to point out **why** it works.

Comment: @LotPings: Glad to hear it, but suggest that if you want to _point out_ something you _already know to be true_, don't phrase it as a _question_.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this is a regex `-match`:

```
PS> $strings='* one','two','* three'
PS> $strings.Where({$_ -match  '^\* '})
* one
* three
```

Comment: Thanks (+1) - I've removed my previous comment (and will remove this one).

Answer (score 0):

[Your own answer based on Ansgar Wiecher's helpful comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54816938/45375) and [Gert Jan Kraaijeveld's helpful alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54816975/45375) both provide effective solutions.

The most immediate solution is to *escape* the `*` char. in your wildcard expression, which can be done with a *backtick* (`` ` ``), but note that it must be placed inside a *single-quoted* string (`'...'`):

```
PS> '* foo' -like '`* *'  
True
```